# Accessing OAUTH2 api using phonegap

Tags: ios, api, cordova, oauth, childbrowser

I am developing an html5 hybrid app which needs to access an oauth2 api.

I am looking what should be the best plugin I should use to implement this task.

Based on my research, I've found two possible plugins which are "ChildBrowser and InAppBrowser".

What plugin should I use? Currently, I'm picking up the "ChildBrowser" in which I tried to follow using the below link.

https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso/blob/master/README-Phonegap.md

It seems that the documentation is quite not updated (ex. Cordova.plist was removed and use the config.xml instead).

I've followed the instruction step by step on the above link until "Setting up your WebApp with ChildBrowser" and I get build error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cordova's InAppBrowser` and do Oauth2 login using this jQuery plugin:
https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2

There is a working example for phonegap.